# Infinite slick carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, slick.js

I am using AngularJs directive angular-slick-carousel: https://github.com/devmark/angular-slick-carousel

It's an AngularJs directive for jquery slick carousel plug-in.

I have slick with dynamic data in infinite mode. I would like the numbers to increment or decrement, regarding the direction slick is moving. Although my data changes, slick is reseting to default values everytime it hits the edge. I bealive it is because the values are cloned at initialization so it gives an appirance of infinity. Is there any way to fix this? 
Here is my plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/mzbO1e?p=preview

controller:

```
$scope.slickData=[
{value:0},
{value:1},
{value:2},
{value:3},
{value:4},
{value:5},
{value:6}];
$scope.slickConfig={
slidesToShow: 5,
slidesToScroll: 1,
enabled: true,
infinite: true,
arrows: true,
initialSlide: 1,
method: {},
event:{
  beforeChange: function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
                $scope.slickLoaded=false;
                if(currentSlide==0&&nextSlide==6){
                    $scope.slickData[nextSlide].value=$scope.slickData[currentSlide].value-1;
                }else if(currentSlide==2&&nextSlide==3){
                    $scope.slickData[0].value=$scope.slickData[6].value+1;
                }else if(currentSlide>nextSlide&&!(nextSlide==0&&currentSlide==6)){
                    $scope.slickData[nextSlide].value=$scope.slickData[currentSlide].value-1;
                }else if(currentSlide>1){
                    $scope.slickData[currentSlide-2].value=$scope.slickData[currentSlide-3].value+1;
                }else if(currentSlide==0&&nextSlide==1){
                    $scope.slickData[5].value=$scope.slickData[4].value+1;
                }else if (currentSlide==1&&nextSlide==2){
                    $scope.slickData[6].value=$scope.slickData[5].value+1;
                }
                $scope.slickLoaded=true;
            },
}}
$scope.slickLoaded=true;
```

html:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="SlickController">
<slick ng-if="slickLoaded" settings="slickConfig">
  <div ng-repeat="slide in slickData track by $index">
    <h3>{{$index}}</h3>
    <h3>{{slickData[$index].value}}</h3>
  </div>
</slick>
<div ng-repeat="slide in slickData track by $index">
    {{$index}} : {{slickData[$index]}}
</div>
```